# Como fazer uma contagem de quantos candidatos há nessa página ? Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo, python-2.7

Coisa simples. Preciso fazer uma contagem de quantos candidatos tem na tabela desta ´página, por exemplo : http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=70
 Por exemplo lá tem 110 nomes, mas eu preciso pegar esse número e tenho que fazer isso em um número enorme de páginas com a mesma estrutura. Eis oq ue já tentei :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
import re
import urllib
r = requests.get('http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-    de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=70')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
contador = 0
for node in soup.findAll(".XXX-XX<"):
  contador = contador+1
print(contador)
```

Só que ele não tá achando esses caracteres sendo que eles estão lá, na coluna de cpf, por exemplo...
 Como fazer isso ?

Comment: Não serve contar quantos elementos <td> tem na tabela <table id="sisu">?

Comment: Tu vais percorrer todas as páginas? http://....&id_grupo=70, http://....&id_grupo=71 ... E incrementar o numros de candidatos numa só variável?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se for só mesmo para saber quantos candidatos há:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

req = requests.get('http://www.ufjf.br/cdara/sisu-2/sisu-2017-1a-edicao/lista-de-espera-sisu-3/?id_curso=01GV&id_grupo=70')
soup = bs(req.text, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.select('#sisu tr')
print(len(rows[1:])) # 110
```

[Instalação do BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup)

Nota que faço `rows[1:]` pois a primeira row (`<tr>`) são os nomes das colunas (acho que não contam como candidato)

Answer (score 1):

```
print(len(re.findall('XXX-XX', str(soup))))
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
import HTMLParser
import urllib2
import re
from pprint import pprint

request = urllib2.Request("websiteURL")

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

responseContent = response.read()

# Aqui pelo que reparei o que precisas é pegar apenas o conteudo da primeira coluna de cada linha, para isso a utilização desta regular expression e do findall
match = re.findall(r'<tr></td>(.*)</td>', responseContent)

# Depois de teres o code podes fazer o que bem desejares, contar, imprimir...
for code in match:
    print code
```

Penso que o código está a funcionar perfeitamente, se tiver algum erro podes simplesmente corrigir pois pela lógica o que tu queres está aqui